# Remove/Delete ":" Colon in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dont have access to the following HTML its displayed dynamically using some External JS.

```
<td class="quantitybox">
    <span class="qty">Quantity</span>
    <br style="clear:both;">
    :<input type="text" value="1" onkeydown="javascript:QtyEnabledAddToCart();" maxlength="8" size="3" name="QTY.1121309" class="v65-productdetail-cartqty">
</td>
```

I want that : after   to be Removed/Deleted using Jquery, but i am not getting what handler should be used shall i apply a class to `<br>` dynamically and do something to it

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you want?

Comment: Can you see the ":" COLON after <br style="clear:both;"> i want to remove it dynamically using JQuery

Comment: just do `$("td.quantitybox").html($(this).html().replace(": <", "<"));`

Comment: @mattytommo. IF you want to use `html` better use the overload that accept a function.

Comment: `.html` removes the existing elements, so if they have jQuery events or data, it will cause bugs

Comment: @Esailija. See my updated answer, it can be done!

Comment: @gdoron sure but, still, using `.html` will destroy the existing elements and remove all their data and handlers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery way, without `regex`:

```
$('td.quantitybox').contents().filter(function(){       
    return this.nodeType === 3  && // textNode
           $.trim(this.nodeValue) === ":";
}).remove();
```

**Or simply change the textnode to an empty string:**

```
$('td.quantitybox').contents().filter(function(){       
    return this.nodeType === 3  && // textNode
           $.trim(this.nodeValue) === ":";
})[0].nodeValue = "";
```

**If you have multiple textnode with colons- `:` that you want to remove:**

```
$('td.quantitybox').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && // textNode
    $.trim(this.nodeValue) === ":";
}).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = "";
});​
```

**If you want to do it with `regex` and aware of it's risks:**

```
$('td.quantitybox').html(function(i, old){
    return old.replace(/:\s*</, '<');
});
```

Note that your HTML code in the question was edited, so I added the white space to the regex so it will work with the initial markup as well....

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, though currently untested, the following:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    var i = this.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        text = i.previousSibling.nodeValue.replace(/:/g, '');
    i.previousSibling.nodeValue = text;
});​
```

Comment: +1. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10798487/601179) looks exactly like your answer, but with `map`, can you explain to me what he's trying to do?

Comment: What he's doing is apparently trying to use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to create an array comprised of the text of the element. Though I don't think it'll work, since (like `filter()`) I believe that `map()` requires a `return variableOrExpressionName` statement with which to populate that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var texts = $('input').map(function(){
        var text = this.previousSibling.nodeValue;
       this.previousSibling.nodeValue = text.replace(/:/g, '');
   });
});​
```

Comment: What is `map` doing here? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k25yx/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Cache Object
    var obj  = $('.quantitybox');

    obj.each(function(){
       var that = $(this);

       // remove br          
       that.find('br').remove();

       // trim colon  
       that.html(function(i, val) {
           return val.replace(':', '');
       });
    })
});
```